# bootstrap 3 - collapse menu earlier

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Trying to figure out how I can collapse the menu earlier? Is there any easy way to do this in bootstrap 3?

The problem with my code atm, is that it opens, and closes automatic? really don't understand why that is happening.

```
@media (max-width: 970px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        margin: 7.5px -15px;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="top_menu_wrap">
  <div class="navbar-header navbar-right">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right">
    <ul id="menu-menu-1" class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li id="menu-item-4" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-4 active"><a title="Forsiden" href="http://localhost/wpdev/">Forsiden</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-75" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-75 dropdown">
        <a title="Om Oss" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" aria-haspopup="true">Om Oss <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu">
          <li id="menu-item-22" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-22"><a title="Om Oss" href="http://localhost/wpdev/om-oss/">Om Oss</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-64" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-64"><a title="Vår trening" href="http://localhost/wpdev/var-trening/">Vår trening</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-76" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-76"><a title="Våre ansatte" href="http://localhost/wpdev/vare-ansatte-2/">Våre ansatte</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-82" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-82"><a title="Priser" href="http://localhost/wpdev/priser/">Priser</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-51" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-51"><a title="Timeplan" href="http://localhost/wpdev/timeplan/">Timeplan</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-63" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-63"><a title="Timebeskrivelse" href="http://localhost/wpdev/timebeskrivelse/">Timebeskrivelse</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-74" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-74"><a title="Bli medlem" href="http://localhost/wpdev/bli-medlem/">Bli medlem</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like it's working.. look at these fiddles.
http://jsfiddle.net/cKS53/
And without your media queries
http://jsfiddle.net/cKS53/1/
The only thing I added to your html is (at the top) 
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your question, u only have to adjust your media-query. 
Set max-width to e.g. 500px will collapse your Menu if your view is bigger than 500px ...

Hope this helps ...

Comment: The problem with my code atm, is that it opens, and closes automatic? really don't understand why that is happening. So when it IS closed, and i try to "open" the menu, it closes itself.. Nothing to do with max-width.

Comment: ok that is realy no normal behaviour.. maybe you can make a fiddle with your code. I think there must be a wrong display: block in your list items classes e.g dropdown-menu or menu-item, menu-item-type-post_type ...